# Proving ${n \choose k}={n \choose n-k}$ using a bijection

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $S$ be an $n$-order set. Prove by bijection that the number of $k$-order subsets is equal to the number of $(n-k)$-order subsets: $${n \choose k}={n \choose n-k}.$$

Could someone help me figure out how to begin proving this? Supposedly, I have to associate an arbitrary $k$-order subset with its complement in the beginning. But where do I go from there, or is there an easier way to go about solving this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is good. You want to map a set to its complement. What you must do now is show that your mapping is bijective.

On one side, you have the set $X=\{A| A\subseteq S\wedge |A|=k\}$. On the other, you have $Y=\{A|A\subseteq S\wedge |A| = n-k\}$. You know that $|X| = {n\choose k}$ and $|Y|={n\choose n-k}$, so you must prove $|X|=|Y|$.

You say that the mapping $F:X\rightarrow Y$, defined by $A\mapsto A^c$ is a bijection. For that, you must prove:

- It is well defined, meaning $A^c\in Y$ for all $A\in X$
- It is injective, meaning that if $A\neq B$, $F(A)\neq F(B)$
- It is surjective, meaning that for all $C\in Y$, you can find such an $A\in X$ that $F(A)=C$.

Answer (score 0):

From a set of $n$ elements say $X$

- choosing a subset of $k$ elements $A$ would give me a set of $n-k$ elements $X-A$.....
- choosing a subset of $n-k$ elements $A$ would give me a set of $k$ elements $X-A$.....

Can you see it now??